# ContextMenuConfigurationForRowAt in iOS13

Tags: swift, contextmenu, ios13

In this video in WWDC19 seasons, [Modernizing Your UI for iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/), this method is to create a context menu, but I get an error when using it:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let actionProvider = (suggestedActions: [UIMenuElement])-> UIMenu? // in this line i got an error {
        let editMenu = UIMenu(title: "Edit...", children: [
        UIAction(title: "Copy") {},
        UIAction(title: "Duplicate") {}
        ])
        return UIMenu(children: [
        UIAction(title: "Share") {},
        editMenu,
        UIAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) {}
        ])
    }

    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: "unique-ID" as NSCopying,
                                      previewProvider: nil,
                                      actionProvider: actionProvider)
}
```

The error appears in the line  `-> UIMenu?` and says `Expected type after '->'`. Could anyone help me how to solve it?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have many syntax errors:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let actionProvider: UIContextMenuActionProvider = { _ in
        let editMenu = UIMenu(title: "Edit...", children: [
            UIAction(title: "Copy") { _ in },
            UIAction(title: "Duplicate") { _ in }
        ])
        return UIMenu(title: "Title", children: [
            UIAction(title: "Share") { _ in },
            editMenu
        ])
    }

    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: "unique-ID" as NSCopying, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: actionProvider)
}
```

Note that some of the API's changed after WWDC and you should consider updating them similar to above code. You can check a comprehensive [Guide to iOS Context Menus](https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide) wrote by Kyle Bashour.

Example:

```
func makeContextMenu() -> UIMenu {
    let rename = UIAction(title: "Rename Pupper", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")) { action in
        // Show rename UI
    }

    // Here we specify the "destructive" attribute to show that it’s destructive in nature
    let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete Photo", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { action in
        // Delete this photo 
    }

    // The "title" will show up as an action for opening this menu
    let edit = UIMenu(title: "Edit...", children: [rename, delete])

    let share = UIAction(...)

    // Create our menu with both the edit menu and the share action
    return UIMenu(title: "Main Menu", children: [edit, share])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { suggestedActions in

        // "puppers" is the array backing the collection view
        return self.makeContextMenu(for: self.puppers[indexPath.row])
    })
}
```

Comment: How to change buttons  title fonts?